# How to "highlight" a div based on a query result?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I'm developing a little aplication for a game.
The application consist in showing where is a given monster. I have a database with monster, maps and maps where monsters belong.

Right now the application is almost working, if a user write "Poring" for example, a list in html will appear with map name and map id.

Anyway, I also have a grid with the whole world of the game, every square in the grid is a map, and each grid have an specific id.

So, lets say I'm looking for "Poring" in the application.

Right now it will show the following list:

```
map: Prontera Field 07 map_id: prt_fild07
map: Prontera Field 08 map_id: prt_fild08
```

but what I want is not to show that list, but highlight the divs (or add any kind of CSS) to the divs with id="prt_fild07" and id="prt_fild08".

I know I need to use AJAX but I'm not sure how, since I'm learning JQuery but anyway, right now I'm using AJAX to display the list.

Here's the JQuery code:

```
    $('#ro-form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default submission

        $.ajax({
            url: 'files/php/process.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(), //serielize form data
            dataType: 'html'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#test').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $('#test').fadeIn('slow').html(data);
            });
        })
        .fail(function(){
            alert(':(');
        });


    });
```

and here is the php part

```
<?php

    include 'connection.php';

    if( $_POST ){
        $mob_id_name = $_POST['mob_id_name'];
    }

    $sql = "select  restartmap.map.map_name, restartmap.map.map_id
            from    restartmap.map, restartmap.map_monster, restartmap.monster
            where   restartmap.map.map_id = restartmap.map_monster.map_monster_map_id and
                    restartmap.monster.monster_id = restartmap.map_monster.map_monster_monster_id and
                    (restartmap.monster.monster_id = '$mob_id_name' 
                    or restartmap.monster.monster_name like '$mob_id_name')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $conn->close();
?>


<div id="result-container">
    <?php
        if($result->num_rows > 0 ){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                print "map: " . $row["map_name"] . " map_id: " .$row["map_id"] . "<br>";
            }
        }else{
            print "<p> nothing :( </p>";
        }


    ?>
</div>
```

Basically what I'm doing is sending from index.php the information to process.php via AJAX and then printing the whole $result var in index.php but what I really want to do is to highlight the divs with the same id as map_id.

Comment: Send the data as array in json format...then iterate array

Comment: dataType should be `json`, use `parse_str($_POST['data'], $data)` than extract whatever you need from `$data` (which will hold the $_POST info), and return an array that is using php `json_encode`, that adds the `$row["map_id"]` values to it so you can use it in your `.done` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your jQuery code to accept `json` as the `dataType`, like so, than in the PHP use `parse_str` to parse out the posted serialized data into an array that you can work with, than just build an array that will be returned to the parameter in the `.done` jquery ajax function.  Am using `$return` in php below, than just `json_encode` this value so that it can be used.

Something like the following below should work nicely.  But you didn't specify what you want inside of those divs, so I just put `Put something in here` text in place of whatever you need in there.

jQuery:

```
$('#ro-form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //Prevent default submission

    var $parentDiv = $('<div />').attr('id', 'result-container');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'files/php/process.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            formData: $(this).serialize()
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(data){

        if (data.hasOwnProperty('msgids'))
        {
            for(var x = 0, len = data['msgids'].length; x < len; x++)
            {
                var $div = $('<div />').attr('id', data['msgids'][x]).text('Put something in here');
                $div.appendTo($parentDiv);
            }
            $('body').append($parentDiv);
        }
    })
    .fail(function(){
        alert(':(');
    });


});
```

php:

```
<?php

    $return = array();

    include 'connection.php';

    if(!empty($_POST['formData']))
    {
        parse_str($_POST['formData'], $data);

        $mob_id_name = $data['mob_id_name'];

        $sql = "select  restartmap.map.map_name, restartmap.map.map_id
            from    restartmap.map, restartmap.map_monster, restartmap.monster
            where   restartmap.map.map_id = restartmap.map_monster.map_monster_map_id and
                    restartmap.monster.monster_id = restartmap.map_monster.map_monster_monster_id and
                    (restartmap.monster.monster_id = '$mob_id_name' 
                    or restartmap.monster.monster_name like '$mob_id_name')";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        $conn->close();

        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $return['msgids'][] = $row['map_id'];
            }
        }

    }

    echo json_encode($return);
    die();

?>
```